# Spring WS returning "No adapter for endpoint" after decrypting SOAP message with Wss4jSecurityInterceptor

Tags: soap, spring-ws, ws-security

I've created a simple Spring WS that sign and decrypt a SOAP message. The message is decrypted but somehow it doesn't hit my Endpoint class. Here is my code:

**pom.xml**

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.9</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example.hr</groupId>
    <artifactId>countryService</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>holidayService Spring-WS Application</name>
    <url>http://www.springframework.org/spring-ws</url>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <finalName>countryService</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>xjc</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xjc</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/templates/</schemaDirectory>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                    <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.wss4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wss4j</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>
```

**sping-ws-servlet.xml**

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="http://com.example.hr" />
    
    
    <sws:annotation-driven />


    <sws:dynamic-wsdl id="countries" portTypeName="CountriesPort" locationUri="/" targetNamespace="example.com/hr">
        <sws:xsd location="/WEB-INF/countries.xsd" />
    </sws:dynamic-wsdl>
    
    <bean id="messageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory"/>
    
    
    <bean id="propertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath*:application.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <sws:interceptors>
        <bean class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.SoapEnvelopeLoggingInterceptor" />
    </sws:interceptors>

    
    <bean id="keyStore" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.support.KeyStoreFactoryBean">
        <property name="location" value="${sec.EncryptionKeyStore}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${sec.KeyStorePassword}"/>
        <property name="type" value="JKS"/>
    </bean>
    
    
    <bean id="keyStoreCallbackHandler" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j2.callback.KeyStoreCallbackHandler">
      <property name="keyStore" ref="keyStore"/>
      <property name="privateKeyPassword" value="${sec.PrivateKeyPassword}"/>
    </bean>
    
    
    <bean id="cryptoFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j2.support.CryptoFactoryBean">
        <property name="keyStoreLocation" value="${sec.EncryptionKeyStore}"/>
        <property name="keyStorePassword" value="${sec.KeyStorePassword}"/>
        <property name="keyStoreType" value="JKS"/>
    </bean>
    
    
    <bean id="wss4jSecurityInterceptor" class="com.example.hr.ws.CustomWss4jSecurityInterceptor">
        <property name="validationActions" value="${sec.ValidationActions}"/>
        <property name="securementActions" value="${sec.SecurementActions}"/>
        <property name="validationTimeToLive" value="${sec.ValidationTTL}"/>
        <property name="securementTimeToLive" value="${sec.SecurementTTL}"/>
        <property name="securementUsername" value="${sec.SecurementUsername}"/>
        <property name="securementPassword" value="${sec.SecurementPassword}"/>
        <property name="securementEncryptionKeyIdentifier" value="${sec.SecurementEncryptionKeyIdentifier}"/>
        <property name="securementSignatureKeyIdentifier" value="${sec.SecurementSignatureKeyIdentifier}"/>
        <property name="securementSignatureParts" value="${sec.SecurementSignatureParts}"/>
        <property name="securementSignatureCrypto" ref="cryptoFactory" />
        <property name="securementEncryptionCrypto" ref="cryptoFactory" />
        <property name="validationDecryptionCrypto" ref="cryptoFactory" />
        <property name="validationSignatureCrypto" ref="cryptoFactory" />
        <property name="validationCallbackHandler" ref="keyStoreCallbackHandler" />
    </bean>
    
    
    <bean id="countryRepository" class="com.example.hr.repository.CountryRepository" /> 
        
    <bean id="countryEndpoint" class="com.example.hr.ws.CountryEndpoint">
        <constructor-arg ref="countryRepository"/>
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="endpointMapping" class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping">
        <property name="interceptors">
            <list>
                <ref bean="wss4jSecurityInterceptor" />
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultEndpoint" ref="countryEndpoint" />
    </bean>

    
    <bean id="messageDispatcher" class="org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher">
        <property name="endpointMappings" ref="endpointMapping" />
    </bean>
    
</beans>
```

**CountryEndpoint.java**

```
@Endpoint
public class CountryEndpoint {
   private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "example.com/hr/schemas";
   private CountryRepository countryRepository;
   private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CountryEndpoint.class);


   public CountryEndpoint(CountryRepository countryRepository) throws JDOMException {
      this.countryRepository = countryRepository;
   }
   
   
   @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "getCountryRequest")
   @ResponsePayload
   public GetCountryResponse getCountry(@RequestPayload GetCountryRequest request) 
      throws JDOMException {
      
      Country country = countryRepository.findCountry(request.getName());
      GetCountryResponse response = new GetCountryResponse();
      response.setCountry(country);
      logger.info("========================================");
      logger.info("============== RESPONSE ================");
      logger.info("========================================");
      return response;
   }

}
```

**countries.xsd**

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
   xmlns:tns = "example.com/hr/schemas"
   xmlns:wsu = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
   targetNamespace = "example.com/hr/schemas" 
   elementFormDefault = "qualified">

   <xs:element name = "getCountryRequest">
      <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name = "name" type = "xs:string"/>
         </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>

   <xs:element name = "getCountryResponse">
      <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name = "country" type = "tns:country"/>
         </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>

   <xs:complexType name = "country">
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name = "name" type = "xs:string"/>
         <xs:element name = "population" type = "xs:int"/>
         <xs:element name = "capital" type = "xs:string"/>
         <xs:element name = "currency" type = "tns:currency"/>
      </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>

   <xs:simpleType name = "currency">
      <xs:restriction base = "xs:string">
         <xs:enumeration value = "GBP"/>
         <xs:enumeration value = "USD"/>
         <xs:enumeration value = "INR"/>
      </xs:restriction>
   </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

**SOAP ENVELOPE**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sch="example.com/hr/schemas">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <sch:getCountryRequest>
         <sch:name>U.S</sch:name>
      </sch:getCountryRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The message is decrypted, since I see it printed in the logs, but then I receive the below error message:

```
   <soapenv:Body xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="id-811A8CD4ECA47EB92F1679415081841773">
      <sch:getCountryRequest>
         <sch:name>U.S</sch:name>
      </sch:getCountryRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
2023-03-21 16:12:42 DEBUG SoapMessageDispatcher - Testing endpoint adapter [org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter@60f7ea28]
2023-03-21 16:12:54 DEBUG SoapMessageDispatcher - Testing endpoint adapter [org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.GenericMarshallingMethodEndpointAdapter@69afb721]
2023-03-21 16:12:57 DEBUG SoapMessageDispatcher - Testing endpoint adapter [org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.MarshallingMethodEndpointAdapter@70c93a12]
2023-03-21 16:13:03 DEBUG SoapFaultAnnotationExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from endpoint [com.example.hr.ws.CountryEndpoint@87248c3]: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No adapter for endpoint [com.example.hr.ws.CountryEndpoint@87248c3]: Is your endpoint annotated with @Endpoint, or does it implement a supported interface like MessageHandler or PayloadEndpoint?
2023-03-21 16:13:03 DEBUG SimpleSoapExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from endpoint [com.example.hr.ws.CountryEndpoint@87248c3]: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No adapter for endpoint [com.example.hr.ws.CountryEndpoint@87248c3]: Is your endpoint annotated with @Endpoint, or does it implement a supported interface like MessageHandler or PayloadEndpoint?
2023-03-21 16:13:03 DEBUG SoapMessageDispatcher - Endpoint invocation resulted in exception - responding with Fault
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No adapter for endpoint [com.example.hr.ws.CountryEndpoint@87248c3]: Is your endpoint annotated with @Endpoint, or does it implement a supported interface like MessageHandler or PayloadEndpoint?
    at deployment.countryService.war//org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.getEndpointAdapter(MessageDispatcher.java:291)
```

My schema classes are correctly annotated with *@XmlRootElement* from `javax.xml.bind.annotation`, e.g.

```
package com.example.hr.schemas;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "name"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "getCountryRequest")
public class GetCountryRequest {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String name;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the name property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the name property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setName(String value) {
        this.name = value;
    }

}
```

When I debug the code, the `MessageDispatcher.dispatch` method fails to get an EndpointAdapter for CountryEndpoint class: when executing `getEndpointAdapter` method it checks the condition `if (endpointAdapter.supports(endpoint))`

and it appears that my CountryEndpoint is not an instance of `org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.MethodEndpoint`.

I also tried using `org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller` in my Spring WS Configuration and JAXBElement in my CountryEndpoint as shown below but it didn't work:

```
 @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "getCountryRequest")
   @ResponsePayload
   public JAXBElement<GetCountryResponse> getCountry(@RequestPayload JAXBElement<GetCountryRequest> request) 
      throws JDOMException {
      
      Country country = countryRepository.findCountry(request.getValue().getName());
      GetCountryResponse response = new GetCountryResponse();
      response.setCountry(country);
      logger.info("========================================");
      logger.info("============== RESPONSE ================");
      logger.info("========================================");
      return new JAXBElement<GetCountryResponse>(QName.valueOf("GetCountryResponse"), GetCountryResponse.class, response);
   }
```

I really don't understand what I'm missing here. Can anybody help me please?

Thank you!

Comment: For starters you are using SPring Boot so why so many additional dependencies and the `spring-ws-servlet.xml`? Spring Boot takes care of most of it? Why the wrapping in a `JaxbElement` as you have a proper `@XmlRootElelment` in your model you shouldn't need it.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum: some extra dependencies were related to JAXBElement, which I included just because some people in other Stackoverflow threads mentioned that this is what was missing to make it work (but I agree with you: I don't understand why that should be a requirement, especially considering it is not mentioned in the Spring documentation). Truth is: I don't fully understand the difference between Spring Boot and Spring, but I'm happy to either remove the extra dependencies or to switch from Spring Boot to a different parent. Do you think the extra dependencies might cause a conflict?

Comment: By the way @M.Deinum, I've created another pom to remove the dependencies from Spring Boot and only use Spring Framework 6 but nothing changed unfortunately... Thank you

Comment: I have no idea what you are doing, are you using Spring Boot or not? If not remove the tag and show how you are bootstrapping things.

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum, I've imported the dependency for Bootstrap, but I'm not using it the way I've seen it's used, i.e. using a ServletInitializer and a static main method to run the application. I just package the solution as a WAR file and deploy on WildFly 27. I'm also trying make use of Beans in my spring-ws-servlet.xml file as much as I can, as opposed to create things like WebServiceConfig to setup WSDL, Interceptors, etc.
Does it make sense?

Comment: No it doesn't as you are duplicating things that are done for you out-of-the-box by spring boot. The servlet initializer is the replacement for the web.xml and the java config for the xml.

Comment: Got ya, @M.Deinum. But beside this duplication, theoretically it should still work since I can start the application, receive and decrypt the SOAP message. I switched to just use Spring Framework 6 but no joy: same issue...

Comment: Well not just the duplication also the misconfiguration. The problem is you manually configure things but haven't included something that knows how to execute the `@Endpoint` it only knows how to map but not execute. So yes partially it is because of not using things properly and trying to configure everything manually. Why the MessageDispatcher, the endpoint, the endpointmapping etc. those aren't needed as those are auto configured. I don't really understand what you are doing and what the current state is as there is a lot of coflicting stuff in your question.

Comment: Sorry @M.Deinum, my understanding is that once you register the Endpoint with the annotation it automatically knows how to execute it. The MessageDipatcher is something that I included out of desperation (lol) but its presence/absence didn't seem to change anything. I configured the Endpoint and EndpointMapping because it seems I had to do so when adding the interceptors and defining the defaultEndpoint for PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping. What I'm trying to do is signing and decrypting a SOAP message, and trigger the right response from my Endpoint (and encrypt the response back)

Comment: On another note: what do you mean by saying "haven't included something that knows how to execute the Endpoint it only knows how to map but not execute."? What's missing to execute the Endpoint? PayloadRoot annotation is in my Endpoint to match the incoming SOAP message, and I've configured the Interceptor to sign and decrypt the message: what am I missing to execute the Endpoint? Thank you for your help @M.Deinum :)

Comment: I know what you are trying to do but your code and configuration is conflicting and duplication is present in abundance. Stuff you are doing is already handled by either `sws:annotatio-driven` or `sws:interceptors`. You are going around those and add a lot of clutter. I have also no idea in what state your endpoint is as it seems you tried multiple things.

Comment: The thing, the thing that knows how to handle your `@PayloadRoot` an annotation is only metadata nothing more nothing less. You only have the mapping (which interferes with `sws:annotation-driven` and not the componet for the execution the `EndpointAdapter` you only have the `EndpointMapping`. Partially due to you deciding to not use the defaults (Spring BOot) but do everything manually.

Comment: My Endpoint hasn't changed actually, so it is as I copied in the original question. I've only played with spring-ws-servlet.xml file. If I remove the configuration for PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping, and use <sws:interceptors> instead, the SOAP message is not decrypted (so the wss4jSecurityInterceptor is not seen). Is there anywhere a working example of how to correctly achieve the same of what I'm (incorrectly) trying to do?

Comment: You need to tell sws:interceptors that it needs to use your interceptor, if you don't it obviously won't see it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would by starting to cleanup your Spring WS configuration there are conflicting parts in there.

1. Fix the `component-scan` it needs a proper base package
2. Properly configure interceptors
3. Properly use `sws:annotation-driven`.

```xml
<beans>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example.hr" />
    
    <sws:annotation-driven />

    <sws:dynamic-wsdl id="countries" portTypeName="CountriesPort" locationUri="/" targetNamespace="example.com/hr">
        <sws:xsd location="/WEB-INF/countries.xsd" />
    </sws:dynamic-wsdl>
    
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:application.properties"/>

    <sws:interceptors>
        <bean class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.SoapEnvelopeLoggingInterceptor" />
        <ref bean="wss4jSecurityInterceptor" />
    </sws:interceptors>
    
    <bean id="keyStore" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.support.KeyStoreFactoryBean">
        <property name="location" value="${sec.EncryptionKeyStore}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${sec.KeyStorePassword}"/>
        <property name="type" value="JKS"/>
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="keyStoreCallbackHandler" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j2.callback.KeyStoreCallbackHandler">
      <property name="keyStore" ref="keyStore"/>
      <property name="privateKeyPassword" value="${sec.PrivateKeyPassword}"/>
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="cryptoFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j2.support.CryptoFactoryBean">
        <property name="keyStoreLocation" value="${sec.EncryptionKeyStore}"/>
        <property name="keyStorePassword" value="${sec.KeyStorePassword}"/>
        <property name="keyStoreType" value="JKS"/>
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="wss4jSecurityInterceptor" class="com.example.hr.ws.CustomWss4jSecurityInterceptor">
        <property name="validationActions" value="${sec.ValidationActions}"/>
        <property name="securementActions" value="${sec.SecurementActions}"/>
        <property name="validationTimeToLive" value="${sec.ValidationTTL}"/>
        <property name="securementTimeToLive" value="${sec.SecurementTTL}"/>
        <property name="securementUsername" value="${sec.SecurementUsername}"/>
        <property name="securementPassword" value="${sec.SecurementPassword}"/>
        <property name="securementEncryptionKeyIdentifier" value="${sec.SecurementEncryptionKeyIdentifier}"/>
        <property name="securementSignatureKeyIdentifier" value="${sec.SecurementSignatureKeyIdentifier}"/>
        <property name="securementSignatureParts" value="${sec.SecurementSignatureParts}"/>
        <property name="securementSignatureCrypto" ref="cryptoFactory" />
        <property name="securementEncryptionCrypto" ref="cryptoFactory" />
        <property name="validationDecryptionCrypto" ref="cryptoFactory" />
        <property name="validationSignatureCrypto" ref="cryptoFactory" />
        <property name="validationCallbackHandler" ref="keyStoreCallbackHandler" />
    </bean>
    
</beans>
```

Next you state that you properly used the `@XmlRootElement` that way you should be able to remove the `JaxbElement`.

```java
@Endpoint
public class CountryEndpoint {
   private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "example.com/hr/schemas";
   private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CountryEndpoint.class);
   private CountryRepository countryRepository;

   public CountryEndpoint(CountryRepository countryRepository) {
      this.countryRepository = countryRepository;
   }   
   
   @PayloadRoot(namespace=NAMESPACE_URI, localPart="getCountryRequest")
   @ResponsePayload
   public GetCountryResponse getCountry(@RequestPayload GetCountryRequest request) {
      
      Country country = countryRepository.findCountry(request.getName());
      GetCountryResponse response = new GetCountryResponse();
      response.setCountry(country);
      logger.info("========================================");
      logger.info("============== RESPONSE ================");
      logger.info("========================================");
      return response;
   }
}
```

Now most of the config in XML isn't needed when using Spring Boot. You would only need the endpoint, the wsdl and the interceptors and all the other stuff is done automatically.

Comment: I changed spring-ws-servlet.xml, (sorry, the component-scan was a typo in my question but it was correct in my file...) removed the unnecessary parts and added 

<sws:interceptors>
        <ref bean="wss4jSecurityInterceptor" />
        <bean class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.SoapEnvelopeLoggingInterceptor" />
</sws:interceptors>

 instead as you suggested, but I'm getting "No endpoint mapping found for [SaajSoapMessage {http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#}EncryptedData]" so now it's not decrypting the message, i.e. the Interceptor doesn't seem to be called

Comment: Your interceptor is an `EndpointInterceptor`?

Comment: My interceptor extends org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j2.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor, so if I go back to the inheritance chain yes, it extends EndpointInterceptor.

Comment: By the way, I also used directly the original Wss4jSecurityInterceptor instead of my custom Interceptor just to check it wasn't causing conflicts or that I had somehow the wrong implementation, but I got the same result...

Comment: In theory this should just work (tm) if it doesn't there must be more to your config and things that you show here.

Comment: That's all I have really. I'll try to start all over again from the scratch but I feel like I'm hitting a wall, as I tried so many different configurations. The only one that seemed to work is when I included the interceptor inside PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping with regards to the decryption part, and in my understanding that's the correct way of doing because the message needs to be transformed before it can be handled by the Endpoint. I couldn't find any real (and recent) working example. Interestingly, this is working in a veeery old implementation (Java 7 and Spring WS 2)...

Comment: Interesting: if I change from PayloadRoot to Action annotation, it decrypts the message, but then it throws an exception in AbstractSoapMessage.getPayloadSource(): "java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.TextImpl cannot be cast to class jakarta.xml.soap.Node (com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.TextImpl is in module java.xml of loader 'bootstrap'; jakarta.xml.soap.Node is in unnamed module of loader 'jakarta.xml.soap.api@1.0.0.Final' @69ee81fc)".... I'll try to rebuild this from the scratch...